# What is the "right" way to work with struct pointers and a C interface?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to setup a system where I pass around a pointer to a structure while hiding the definition of the structure from the end user.  I have two options that seem to work, but I don't know if I'm making this harder than it needs to be, missing a trade off, or just doing something really stupid.  I am stuck with C for any approach and can't use C++.  Additionally, this will eventually need to talk to a Fortran program through, and I'm trying to make that as straightforward as possible.

I have a little utility to demonstrate the concept.  Option one uses a void pointer to a pointer so that I can return a status integer from the function, if necessary.  However, I don't like having to malloc before the call as I'm concerned about the Fortran side of things.  This may be unfounded as I haven't done that demo, yet.  Option two just returns a void pointer from the function, but I lose the ability to do a status return that way.  With both versions, I do have a custom free function, even if not necessarily with the exact current implementation. The struct has it's own void pointer that will be defined based off the option input, and it will need to free that as part of the teardown process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct State
{
    int type;
    void *data;
};

int Init1(int option, void **state);
void* Init2(int option);

void printState(void *state);

void free1(void **state);
void free2(void *state);

void* allocateData(int option);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void **ps1;
    void *s2;
    int ret;
    
    ps1 = malloc(sizeof(void*));
    ret = Init1(1, ps1);
    printState(*ps1);
    free1(ps1);

    s2 = Init2(2);
    printState(s2);
    free2(s2);

    return 0;
}

int Init1(int option, void **state)
{
    (*state) = malloc(sizeof(struct State));
    struct State* ret = *state;
    ret->type = option;
    
    return 0;
}

void free1(void **state)
{
    free(*state);
    free(state);
}

void* Init2(int option)
{
    struct State* ret = malloc(sizeof(struct State));
    ret->type = option;

    return ret;
}

void free2(void *state)
{
    free(state);
}

void printState(void *state)
{
    struct State* data = state;

    printf("Type : %d\n", data->type);
}
```

Comment: There's no need for `void *`.  The user can declare `struct State *s` without ever knowing the members of the struct.

Comment: Agree with @WilliamPursell - check up on "opaque structures".

Comment: Also, there's no need for the initial malloc.  You can do `void *ps1; Init1(1, &ps1);`

Comment: If you use void pointers, you lose a lot of the type safety that C provides.  Don't design an interface with void pointers.  Use opaque types, or pointers to opaque types.  See the standard I/O library and the FILE pointer type for an example

Comment: From a quick read on opaque pointers, it looks like it can add a level of complication when interfacing in Fortran, though still possible.  Thanks for the tip on the initial malloc.

Comment: Why do you need status code return from init function? If initialization fails, then do necessary clean up in that function and simply return NULL to indicate failure.

Comment: I think I will be forced at some part for a void pointer, but it may only be the internal pointer in the struct as I really won't know the type until runtime based on the input option, which is why I have the pointer and the option side-by-side to at least try to manage it.  Normally, this is something I would have done with polymorphism in C++, but that's been blocked from me, so I'm trying to figure out how to mimic it in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look to the `FILE` type in `stdio.h` as an example.  You can expose the type name without exposing its definition:

```
/**
 * State.h
 */
#ifndef STATE_H
#define STATE_H

/**
 * Create a typedef name for the *incomplete* type "struct State"
 */
typedef struct State STATE;

/**
 * Define your interface
 */
void   Init1( int, STATE ** );
STATE *Init2( int );

void   printState( STATE * );

void   sFree( STATE * );
void   sFree2( STATE ** );

#endif
```

Then you complete the definition of the type in the implementation file:

```
/**
 * State.c
 */
#include "State.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
...

/**
 * Complete the type definition
 */
struct State {
  int type;
  void *data;
};

/**
 * Implement the interface
 */
int Init1( int option, STATE **s )
{
  *s = malloc ( sizeof **s ); // type definition is complete at this
  if ( *s )                   // point so we can use sizeof
  {
    (*s)->type = option;
  }
  return *s != NULL; // I'm *assuming* you want to return true (1)
}                    // if the allocation is successful

...
```

Now, when it comes to interoperating with Fortran ... I can't be that much help.  I did that, once, on a VAX, 30-some-odd years ago, and it didn't involve opaque types like this.

Comment: I was able to do the Fortran interface using `type(c_ptr)` in the interface while using opaque structs.